# elasticsearch exact match query not working on not_analyzed field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added a mapping for a string field to be not_analyzed: `'house_type':{'type':'string','index': 'not_analyzed'}`

When I query on this field as follows:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "house_type": "apartment"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query does not return any results, although there are entries with house_type as 'apartment' What am I missing here?

Sample document, mapping and query:
https://gist.github.com/shiladitya-bits/b02f2c9fb38ceef03978eb483bcacd53

Comment: Can you show a sample document and your actual mapping?

Comment: Hi can't share the full document structure because it is confidential, but here is a sample with only the required field https://gist.github.com/shiladitya-bits/b02f2c9fb38ceef03978eb483bcacd53

Comment: After trying it again, it works now. Might have done some incorrect config the last time

Comment: Glad you figured it out